# Undefined symbol _main in module c0.ASM in c with struct keyword

Tags: c, turbo-c

When I compile this program, it shows 0 errors and when I run it, it shows **Undefined symbol _main in module c0.ASM in c with structure**

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};
struct node * createNode(int num)
{
  struct node *newNode;
  newNode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  newNode->data=num;
  newNode->next=NULL;
  return newNode;
}
```

Comment: Choose between C and C++

Comment: Please show us how you compile it, and how you run it. That error message it not one I would expect during "running". -- Oh, and Turbo-C is really ancient, stone age in CS, nobody should use it today.

Comment: You need a `main` function.

Comment: can anyone rewrite the code